# UITableView Cells not doing dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm building a UItableView with custom cells that displays images. The problem is that as I scroll down, the previous cells does not seem to do a dealloc and the device memory is filling up.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    CustomTableCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Article *tempArticle = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titel.text = tempArticle.title;
    cell.subTitle.text = tempArticle.subTitle;
    cell.category.text = tempArticle.category;
    if(tempArticle.imageUrl){
        [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempArticle.imageUrl]];
    } else {
        cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cells are not deallocated by the table view, because they are reused. If you put a breakpoint inside your `if`, you'd notice that after the initial load, it will not stop in there anymore, because the table is able to dequeue an existing cell. The problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: You are guessing that the cells are not being released. Run your app through instruments and take a couple of memory snapshots to see exactly which objects are using memory.

Comment: Okay, I. Get that it is reused, but why is it filling up the memory?

Comment: Not sure how to use instruments, but added a picture of it.

Comment: Add an `autorelease` in the allocation statement.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns a re-used cell or creates one, there-for the if-statement will never be triggered. @LeoNatan

Comment: @vikingosegundo That is only correct if `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` were used.

Comment: @LeoNatan, according to the docs you must register. And if no your comment only make sense if that is mentioned. It is mentioned now.

Comment: @vikingosegundo It is most definitely not required to register a class or nib. It is more convenient, but not required.

Comment: *Important: You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.* And in the past I had more than one crash for not registering. If you use storyboards it is calld for you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that the memory increase is due to the image loading & caching. The `AFnetworking` it's using a `NSCache` instance to cache the downloaded images, this cache is performed in memory and it will be drained when the system decide it has low memory, this is not an issue.

Also the `imageNamed` method caches the images that are loaded in the same way as `AFNetworking`.

In order to check if you have a leak or something is not working properly with your data, check if the memory increases after you scroll back up, if the memory stays the same, than you don't have a problem nor a leak (also you can check leaks with instruments), the cached images are the ones that cause the increase of memory.

Also remove the view controller (pop, remove) from the stack, this will cause some deallocations on the text, labels or other data (not images), if the memory decrease (it won't be a substantial decrease) then you are on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you are setting the reuse identifier correctly.

Maybe it's filling the memory because you're using *AFNetworking* library and **downloading** the images for your cells? Define "filling up the memory" more exactly please.

Comment: Okay, when I mean "filling up the memory", I mean that as a scroll down more of the device memory is used. Which is probably the image that takes up the memory. And even if I delete  [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempArticle.imageUrl]];
it is still taking up more memory as a scroll down but not as much. Which is the text i guess.